# dynamically creating a popup in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html

I am attempting to dynamically create popup tooltips with minimal markup (as there will be a lot of them in the end).

In my markup I have `<div id='help_roles-description'>...</div>`

I make an ajax call to the server to retrieve the helptexts and process them like this:

```
// If there are helptext updates, setup them accordingly
if (typeof response.helptexts != "undefined") {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.helptexts.length; i++) {
        if(response.helptexts[i].html.length) {
            var help_label = $("#help_" + response.helptexts[i].id + "");
            if(help_label) {
                // First of call, create the popup
                help_label.closest('div[data-role=dialog]').append($("<div></div>")
                        .attr("id", "#helptext_" + response.helptexts[i].id + "")
                        .attr("data-role", "popup")
                        .addClass("ui-content")
                        .html(response.helptexts[i].html)
                        .trigger("create")
                        );

                // Store the html DOM that is inside the label, so we can wrap it in an anchor
                var html = help_label.html();
                help_label.empty();
                help_label.append($("<a></a>")
                        .attr("href", "#helptext_" + response.helptexts[i].id)
                        .attr("data-rel", "popup")
                        .addClass("helper_link")
                        .html(html)
                        );

                // Output happyness
                logger("Setting help for '" + "#helptext_" + response.helptexts[i].id + "" + "' to '" + response.helptexts[i].html+ "'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In one example an id is `roles-description`. I do not get a div created with the id `helptext_roles-description`, populated with the html in the response as I expected, Instead I get this:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="#helptext_roles-description-placeholder">
    <!-- placeholder for #helptext_roles-description -->
</div>
```

I have tried googling this but there seems to a woeful lack of things with my search terms, and searching placeholders brings back lots of stuff on inputs.

Where I use the `closest('div').prepend` I have tried appending, pre and appending directly to the `help_label`, and doing it to `help_label.parent()`

I have even taken out the .html, and .trigger bits to be outside the creation process.

I also tried creating the div with the id like this `$("<div id='...` but I always only get the placeholder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First mistake, popups should be appended into page div. page div should direct parent of a popup div.

Comment: I initially started with the html markup, and then programified it. When I wrote the expected markup it works fine. I guess the attr has some cleverness in it. I am also using a dialog, not a page (markup worked fine) and I changed it to `help_label.closest('div[data-role=dialog]').append($("<div></div>")` but I still only get the placeholder.

Comment: Well, I don't think its possible to open a popup within a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments by @Omar above i did a little more digging.

Even though you can specifically write the HTML markup to work fine with a dialog, the `attr("data-rel", "popup")` and `$.popup()` have something special in them that stops this form working unless there is a parent with `data-role="content"`. Since dialogs have a `data-role='main'` You cannot programmatically create popups to use as tooltips in a dialog.

I have currently resorted to using the title attribute of a span not an anchor in my text above.

It's unfortuante that this cannot be handed within jquery, but adding [qtip](http://qtip2.com/) makes these work a whole lot better.

Comment: you can create your own _tip_ without the need to use any plugin.

Comment: I thought this would be a bit of a big job with handling viewports and scrolls etc, qtip does a pretty job. Do you know of any good resources on how to do this, as I'm just worrying about a validation issue which means I may have to start validating things myself.... I thought of creating qtips on the fly.

Comment: I made this before, it's not final, it needs some enhancement. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7kG3k/